# Make: Is it possible to have a target executed in the event of an error (like .DELETE_ON_ERROR removes targets on error)

Tags: makefile

I have some mountpoints that are created as targets and mounted for the purpose of creating another target.  When that other target is made, they must be unmounted, which is relatively simple, using some other .PHONY target to do this.  However, in the event of an error, they still need to be unmounted.  Is it possible to have make do this based on some target that has to be remade when an error occurs?  I know typically make stops processing recipes when an error is encountered.  The only viable option I have come up with is to perform a submake:

```
virtual_target:
    sudo mount somelocation somepath ; \
    $(MAKE) real_target ; \ ret=$$? \
    sudo umount -fl somepath ; \
    exit $$ret

real_target:
    echo "Do something magical"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around it by not mounting the locations as targets, instead creating a macro to mount them.  Then I just set a trap in the recipe to unmount them on exit:

```
target:
    trap "$(umount)" EXIT ; \
    $(mount) && \
    echo "Do something magical"
    touch $@
```